# Can not connect to an already active screen through system() in c

Tags: c, bash, shell, gnu-screen

Here is the part of code I have written to stuff 0 to a screen session open in one of my Ubuntu terminal tabs.

```
char command[60];
strcpy( command, "screen -S 8305.pts-1.MYUb  -X stuff $'0'" );
system(command);
```

It gets compiled fine with only a warning like

```
ignoring return value of ‘system’,
```

But when it comes to running I get the message shown below:

```
No screen session found.
```

I have tried system() with other shell commands and it works perfectly fine. The command for screen also works fine when you run it in a terminal session not in c code.

Comment: As what user does the binary executed under ?

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I was running the code in a terminal in which sudo pass had been entered and was permanently kept. Please expand your comment and make it as solution. Thanks

Comment: You can edit the solution I posted with your suggestions and mark it as the answer thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are running the command as a different user than the user that owns the screen. For example running the binary as sudo.

You can run `ps aux` to find the user under which your binary is running as.

To make the system command work you should run it as the user who owns the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are using `-S` which creates a new named screen, and `-X` which submits a command to an already running screen session.

You either want:

```
system( "screen -S 8305.pts-1.MYUb cmd" );
```

OR

```
system( "screen -r 8305.pts-1.MYUb -X cmd" );
```

FYI -- I'm not sure what `stuff $0` is suppose to be, and in the context of the code you supplied is not going to work -- but I believe that a different problem then the one you reported.

From `man(1)` page

> -S sessionname
>   When creating a new session, this option can be used to specify  a meaningful  name for the session.

And

> -X   Send the specified command to a running screen  session.

Comment: I am sure about the screen command that I am passing to system() as it works perfectly fine in bash terminal.

Comment: The error message you quoted is what you get from `-X` when the session is not already running.  FYI -- IF you are trying to start a new screen and submit a command into it, you do NOT need `-X`. IF you are trying to connected to an existing session, the do not use `-S` (which creates a new session), but instead use `-r`