# running screen command from a c program

Tags: c, bash, shell, gnu-screen

Here is the part of code I have written to stuff 0 to a screen session open in one of my Ubuntu terminal tabs.

```
char command[60];
strcpy( command, "screen -S 8305.pts-1.MYUb  -X stuff $'0'" );
system(command);
```

It gets compiled fine with only a warning like

```
ignoring return value of ‘system’,
```

But when it comes to running it does nothing regarding the screen command. Before this, I was getting "No screen session found." error which was fortunately solved by asking about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100830/can-not-connect-to-an-already-active-screen-through-system-in-c/28101250#28101250).

I have tried `system()` with other shell commands and it works perfectly fine. The command for screen also works fine when you run it in a terminal session not in c code.

Comment: Input to screen. I need to input the screen session with value 0.

Comment: I think you should read the `screen` manual carefully, I was reading it and it seems that there is the answer, I don't have enough time to read it now since I am working, but give it a try, you might discover what's wrong.

Comment: Got solved by deleting $ sign.

Comment: Why did you have it in the first place?

Comment: good question. I just had copied the whole command from somewhere since I am a beginner in using screen. :)  Thanks by the way.